# Convert plain text to HTML C#

Tags: c#, html, converting

I have the `ToHtml()` Extension Method

```
public static class StringMethodExtensions
{
    private static string _paraBreak = "\r\n\r\n";
    private static string _link = "<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>";
    private static string _linkNoFollow = "<a href=\"{0}\" rel=\"nofollow\">{1}</a>";

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a copy of this string converted to HTML markup.
    /// </summary>
    public static string ToHtml(this string s)
    {
        return ToHtml(s, false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a copy of this string converted to HTML markup.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="nofollow">If true, links are given "nofollow"
    /// attribute</param>
    public static string ToHtml(this string s, bool nofollow)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int pos = 0;
        while (pos < s.Length)
        {
            // Extract next paragraph
            int start = pos;
            pos = s.IndexOf(_paraBreak, start);
            if (pos < 0)
                pos = s.Length;
            string para = s.Substring(start, pos - start).Trim();

            // Encode non-empty paragraph
            if (para.Length > 0)
                EncodeParagraph(para, sb, nofollow);

            // Skip over paragraph break
            pos += _paraBreak.Length;
        }
        // Return result
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Encodes a single paragraph to HTML.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s">Text to encode</param>
    /// <param name="sb">StringBuilder to write results</param>
    /// <param name="nofollow">If true, links are given "nofollow"
    /// attribute</param>
    private static void EncodeParagraph(string s, StringBuilder sb, bool nofollow)
    {
        // Start new paragraph
        sb.AppendLine("<p>");

        // HTML encode text
        s = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(s);

        // Convert single newlines to <br>
        s = s.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />\r\n");

        // Encode any hyperlinks
        EncodeLinks(s, sb, nofollow);

        // Close paragraph
        sb.AppendLine("\r\n</p>");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Encodes [[URL]] and [[Text][URL]] links to HTML.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">Text to encode</param>
    /// <param name="sb">StringBuilder to write results</param>
    /// <param name="nofollow">If true, links are given "nofollow"
    /// attribute</param>
    private static void EncodeLinks(string s, StringBuilder sb, bool nofollow)
    {
        // Parse and encode any hyperlinks
        int pos = 0;
        while (pos < s.Length)
        {
            // Look for next link
            int start = pos;
            pos = s.IndexOf("[[", pos);
            if (pos < 0)
                pos = s.Length;
            // Copy text before link
            sb.Append(s.Substring(start, pos - start));
            if (pos < s.Length)
            {
                string label, link;

                start = pos + 2;
                pos = s.IndexOf("]]", start);
                if (pos < 0)
                    pos = s.Length;
                label = s.Substring(start, pos - start);
                int i = label.IndexOf("][");
                if (i >= 0)
                {
                    link = label.Substring(i + 2);
                    label = label.Substring(0, i);
                }
                else
                {
                    link = label;
                }
                // Append link
                sb.Append(String.Format(nofollow ? _linkNoFollow : _link, link, label));

                // Skip over closing "]]"
                pos += 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do you see any improvement / issue?

Comment: I personally like the var keyword more than actual types :)

Comment: Are you trying to handle some standard markup language, or are you inventing your own syntax for specifying links?

Comment: I want to use some standard markup language.

Comment: Looks like this code originally came from [here](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/converting-text-to-html)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static string ToHtml(this string s, bool nofollow)
{
    s = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(s);
    string[] paragraphs = s.Split(new string[]{"\r\n\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string par in paragraphs) {
        sb.AppendLine("<p>");
        string p = par.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />\r\n");
        if (nofollow) {
            p = Regex.Replace(p, @"\[\[(.+)\]\[(.+)\]\]", "<a href=\"$2\" rel=\"nofollow\">$1</a>");
            p = Regex.Replace(p, @"\[\[(.+)\]\]", "<a href=\"$1\" rel=\"nofollow\">$1</a>");
        } else {
            p = Regex.Replace(p, @"\[\[(.+)\]\[(.+)\]\]", "<a href=\"$2\">$1</a>");
            p = Regex.Replace(p, @"\[\[(.+)\]\]", "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
            sb.AppendLine(p);
        }
        sb.AppendLine("</p>");
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

In general, if you find yourself with a variable that you pass around through a bunch of static methods (like `nofollow`), it may be time to make those methods not static.

Comment: This code won't compile: you have an `'` char before the string literal in the `s.Split` method call. And the `p` variable is read-only. And you forgot to append `p` to the `sb`. And replacements in the `Regex.Replace` should be `$1` but not the `\\1`.

Comment: Thanks for catching all that. I've edited the post. I also didn't realize C# foreach iteration variables were read-only... seems silly.

Answer (score 1):

**Spacing**

Your spacing is too tight, and you should always expand two-line if statements to use braces for clarity. One StyleCop guideline which works well for spacing is to have a space before and after statements using curly braces.

```
int start = pos;
pos = s.IndexOf(_paraBreak, start);
if (pos < 0)
    pos = s.Length;
string para = s.Substring(start, pos - start).Trim();
```

Looks better as:

```
int start = pos;
pos = s.IndexOf(_paraBreak, start);

if(pos < 0)
{
    pos = s,Length;
}

string para = s.SubString(start, pos - start).Trim();
```

**var**

Prefer `var` when declaring a local variable where it's obvious from the right-hand side of the declaration. This saves time when changing variable types, and also keeps the code shorter:

```
string para = s.SubString(start, pos - start).Trim();
```

Becomes:

```
var para = s.SubString(start, pos - start).Trim();
```

**Naming**

Variable names like `para` and `s` are unhelpful to a maintenance programmer, use longer variable names that describe the purpose of the variable.

**Guard clauses**

You should validate the parameters to your methods. Yes, even the *this* parameter, because somebody can do this:

```
string input = null;

input.ToHTML();
```

Which causes a `NullReferenceException` when it should be an `ArgumentNullException` or a returned empty string.

Comment: Obviously it's a matter of taste, but you really don't need braces AND a blank line of padding for a one statement `if` block. Six lines of code just for a single conditional call or assignment is ridiculous. The blank lines alone do just fine to separate the block, and then you can leave off the braces without visual issue.

Comment: The issue I have with leaving the braces off of single-line if-statements is that (for me at least) I find it harder to register the end of the if statement than if it was wrapped nicely in braces, and so it increases the risk that I try to add another line, thinking it would be part of the if condition, when it wouldn't. I do not personally consider lines of code (when they're not statements) to have a "cost" on modern screens, and giving code room to breathe is better than condensing it, in my opinion.